# Fabricjs - how do I deselect an object and select a group without releasing the mouse button

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have 3 fabric objects on the canvas, a rect and text are grouped as 1 object, then I dynamically create a polygon, and redraw it on object:moving between the group object and another rect. These form what looks like a "speech bubble", with the group and the rect (pointer) both being movable.

What I'd like to achieve is: when the polygon is clicked with the mouse, you can move all 3 objects while holding the mouse down.

So far what I have groups the items together fine, but you can only move all the items if you select the polygon, then *release the mouse button*, then click the group *again*, hold down the mouse and move the group.

I've tried the following canvas methods, thinking they might "deselect" the polygon on click, but none of them appear to work.

```
canvas.deactivateAllWithDispatch();
canvas.deactivateAll();
canvas.discardActiveObject();
```

Jsfiddle of the prototype I have so far is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/beewayne/3y2x3vty/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I messed around a little and the best I got is to manually move the object and the group together until the user lets up the mouse for the first time.

I modified the mousedown listener to look more like this:

```
  shape.on('mousedown', function(evt) {

    var objs = canvas.getObjects();

    var group = new fabric.Group(objs, {status: 'moving'});

    // Relevant code
    var originalX = shape.left,
        originalY = shape.top,
        mouseX = evt.e.pageX,
        mouseY = evt.e.pageY;

    canvas.on('object:moving', function(evt) {
      shape.left = originalX;
      shape.top = originalY;
      group.left += evt.e.pageX - mouseX;
      group.top += evt.e.pageY - mouseY;
      originalX = shape.left;
      originalY = shape.top;
      mouseX = evt.e.pageX;
      mouseY = evt.e.pageY;
    });

    canvas.setActiveGroup(group.setCoords()).renderAll();
  });

  // clean up the listener
  shape.on('mouseup', function(evt) {
    canvas.off('object:moving');
  });
```

I used the mouse offset, since adding the object to the group makes it "jump" a little.  Also, I continuously set the object to the same position, so that it doesn't move within the group.

http://jsfiddle.net/kqfswu4b/1/

Comment: The best you got seems pretty good to me! I only had to make a slight change to 2 lines of code for this to work 100%. Change the binding of the moving event to the polygon, instead of the canvas. The reason for this was that my code was dependent on the canvas object:moving for various things, so calling canvas.off('object:moving') broke stuff. In your fiddle, I couldn't move the top or bottom after selecting the polygon, moving the group, and releasing the mouse. Thanks a lot for your direction! Here's what got it working for me. http://jsfiddle.net/beewayne/3y2x3vty/6/