# Objects move position automatically when trying to select all on mousedown (Fabric.JS)

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

When I use a button to select all objects I am able to move everything fine, and it all stays in position. However if I want to fire the event when I click on a object on the canvas, it does not work as intended.

Here is a Plnk;

http://plnkr.co/edit/iqn5QpBRe30eftoI1z8p?p=preview

I am using this as snippet of code to selectAll;

```
function selectAllCanvasObjects(){
var objs = canvas.getObjects().map(function(o) {
  return o.set('active', true);
});

var group = new fabric.Group(objs, {
  originX: 'center', 
  originY: 'center'
});

canvas._activeObject = null;

canvas.setActiveGroup(group.setCoords()).renderAll();

}
```

When I activate it through a button click, I am able to move all objects on the canvas okay, and they also do not move position on click.

If I activate it the following way;

```
triangle.on('mousedown', function(e){
  selectAllCanvasObjects();
})
```

It will not initialise moving all objects straight away.

If I use;

```
canvas.on('mouse:down', function(e){
  selectAllCanvasObjects();
})
```

It will make the objects automatically jump position.

I am wondering if there is a way I can use the two previous methods so the function behaves like when clicked?

Comment: I think you are messing up the default behavior of `mouse:down` by overwriting it with your handler. If you remove all the other mouse event handlers from the canvas and overwrite `mouse:down` with your handler, then it does exactly the same as your button: http://plnkr.co/edit/ouubVzNi3MTl4rXIQOua?p=preview (first click selects all, second click moves them to `(0, 0)` for whatever reason). I think you are not supposed to overwrite the canvas event handlers, but maybe there is a way to extend them.

Comment: you want to override the mouse:down on the canvas objects, basically what is happening is the default click and drag single object and your click and select all is working at the same time, this creates the weird behavior of your objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding this right, I think I answered a pretty similar question a little while back: [Fabricjs - how do I deselect an object and select a group without releasing the mouse button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38154392/fabricjs-how-do-i-deselect-an-object-and-select-a-group-without-releasing-the/38156169#38156169).

I modified your Plunkr towards that end (example code below): http://plnkr.co/edit/5FN5HYWNjU5I3sZO9ixI?p=preview.  Hopefully this helps you out.

```
triangle.on('mousedown', function(evt) {
  canvas.deactivateAll();
  var objs = canvas.getObjects();

  var group = new fabric.Group(objs, {
    status: 'moving'
  });
  // Relevant code
  var originalX = triangle.left,
    originalY = triangle.top,
    mouseX = evt.e.pageX,
    mouseY = evt.e.pageY;

  triangle.on('moving', function(evt) {
    triangle.left = originalX;
    triangle.top = originalY;
    group.left += evt.e.pageX - mouseX;
    group.top += evt.e.pageY - mouseY;
    originalX = triangle.left;
    originalY = triangle.top;
    mouseX = evt.e.pageX;
    mouseY = evt.e.pageY;
  });

  triangle.on('mouseup', function() {
    triangle.off('moving');
  })

  canvas.setActiveGroup(group.setCoords()).renderAll();
});
```

Comment: Great, it's working well for me! Thanks for the answer :)